# major mode with irony warning message

Tags: major-mode

Below major mode is a dummy mode just derived from c-mode:

```
;; a simple major mode, mylang-mode
(define-derived-mode mylang-mode c-mode
  "major mode for editing mylang language code."
  (message "dummy"))

;; add the mode to the `features' list
(provide 'mylang-mode)
```

But when I switch on this mode by M-x mylang-mode, I always get below warning message:

```
Warning (irony): Major mode is unknown to Irony, see
`irony-supported-major-modes'.
```

I try to add below line to init.el but not helpful:

```
(add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'irony-cdb-autosetup-compile-options)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`irony-supported-major-modes` is the list of major modes known to be compatible with irony, and although your mode extends `c-mode` irony doesn't know that it's supported.  Add your mode to the list with something like `(push 'mylang-mode irony-supported-major-modes)` and the warning ought to go away.